# Multiple individually controlled lights and buttons widely separated

Tags: microcontroller, led, raspberry-pi, button

UPDATED:

I am building a sorting system using lights and buttons. The function is I have multiple items in a bucket I would like to sort to several different bins.

What I would like to have is up to 40 bin areas with an RGB LED push button at each one. Each LED would be individually controlled and it's possible to have them all on at the same time.

Currently I have it working with 4 arcade buttons (single color) using the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi for testing. This RPi uses Electron for a display and communicates with a separate node server I have that does the heavy lifting on logic. I would like to get up to that up to 30-50 light/button combo but obviously don't have enough GPIO pins.

I have made an ESP32/ESP8266 device with LED screen before for another fun small project so my thought was maybe build out each one with its own ESP32 and communicate via MQTT wireless protocol.  Would just need to run a power cable to each device. I was hoping for more of a wired solution with a single bus cable maybe using I2C. But I read I2C cannot handle long distance (over 2 meters). I was reading up on CAN bus which seems like it might work.

From searching around I believe these are called Pick to Light systems. I found this while searching and basically what I want to make with just the big LED button and the screen: https://www.picktolightsystems.com/en/series-products/mwu-series

I noticed the linked system is using only 2 wires for communication and power which I am unsure how that is done and if possible with home microcontrollers like RPis and Arduinos.

Question:

What controllers and communication protocol between the host and the light/button/screen devices is best in this situation? I have the host software working, just the physical side is my main interest.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: `The function is I have multiple items in a bucket I would like to sort to several different bins.` ... you are misunderstanding what the `pick to light` system is ... it has one item type per bin, not mixed items

Comment: @jsotola agreed this is not pick to light exactly.  It would be closer to put to light but instead of put away for storage, it’s put away per group.  So taking multiple items and separating them by some grouped identifier so all contents in each bin would be assigned to the group assigned to the bin making it sorted by group.  Pick to light seemed to be the most widely used terminology to find these systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have workend on such a system previously. I will outline the design decisions and the chosen path - you can reuse it or change it according to your requirements.

**Requirements:**

- Useable for Industrial/Commercial Applications
- Scaleable (Number of bins) and easy to maintain
- Low-Cost hardware
- Maintainable and re-useable code-base (Other projects - won't cover these)

**Basic decisions:**

- Wired over Wireless

We chose to go with "wired", as the bin-controller would need to run 24/7 over long periods without maintenance - therefore a battery solution was out of the question.
We decided: If we already run a wire for the purpose of power, we can use comms alongside it as well.

- Communication interface

As only "un-critical" bandwith and latency is required to drive an array/matrix of bin-controllers we looked at simple options. We chose RS485 over CAN as the physical layer, as the software part was flexible (Not stuck to the CAN-Protocoll) and the driver ICs were cheap and simple to integrate.

- Power bus

As the system was designed for use in an "industrial" environment, we chose to go with a +24V supply provided by some off-shelf SMPS in a cabinet.

- Architecture

We decided, that a single-master multi-slave non-deterministic multi-drop architecture would be best suited.

- Host Controller

We decided to go with an "standard" Windows IPC providing four physical RS485 interfaces. This allowed us, to connect a barcode-reader, a PLC (ERP) and two "strings" of bins to a single IPC.

- Protocoll

We decided to roll our own protocoll to interface with the bin-controllers, as we had no requirements for inter-operability. It is a very basic command based interface with only a few commands implemented (E.g Set_Rgb_Led(255,127,33) or Get_Button_Latch() - see below ). The controller response is fixed for every command in question.

It uses CRC32 and ACK/NACK from the slave, as well as a 16Bit (Future-prove) slave address field.

The Slave-Addresses (Bin-Address) were set via two HEX-rotary switches (8Bit total) on the bin-controllers. This needs to be done only once or upon replacement.

- Software

We chose to go with C in the bin-controller and C# on the IPC, as the ERP-PLC and barcode-reader interface already existed in C#.

**Bin-Controller:**

The Bin-Controller was a custom designed PCB integrating a MCU, a tactile button, a RGB Led, the RS485 transreceiver and the 24V/3v3 DC/DC - simple to design, no real IPXX requirements and no safety/reliability requirements.

It was housed in a custom 3D-printed housing, which was screwed onto the front of the sheet-metal shelf. The RS485/24V cabeling was connected via a simple 4-Way Phoenix push-pull connector-block.

The LED was visible through a front ligth-pipe and the push button was easy to operate even with gloves on (One of these vandalism safe buttons with LED-ring ligth).

**Operation:**

There were three basic operation modes of the system:

- ERP requests a collection of parts to be collected an put into a box.

The Screen connected to the IPC would show a new "Job" and the operator could start it by clicking some buttons and so on. Then, the system would ligth up the bin to get the LED-Ring on the button would indicate the number of items to get by blinking (Usually, three or four items). If the user would push the button, the system was signaled that the next bin is ready for collection.

- User wants to store items to shelfs

The user would tell the system what part-number via the barcode reader and the quantity. The system would then indicate the bin and if the user pushed the button, the "storing" was finished. The system would signal the ERP system.

- User wants to collect parts manually

The user would browse a database and select the item to remove. The bin lights up, the user removes the part and pushes the button. The system signals the ERP.

**Software:**

Basically, no logic was implemented in the bin-controllers. All the business logic (blinking the ring-led n-times) or decrementing a counter up-on a button press and so on where implemented in the host-IPC. This allowed us to make the controller firmware really simple, as it was just a "dumb" slave.

*NOTE: This is only possible, as the system only interacted with the bin in question at a time and "button-presses/ligth LEDs" are not really a "time-critical" task - all runs on "human-speed" instead of "machine-speed".*

The IPC software was more complex, but we had more developers for C# available.

**Overall:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fITRqq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Apendix:**

You can certainly re-use this approach and connect an LCD-Screen to each Bin-Controller.

The Bus-Bandwith to show Images/Text/whatever is certainly enough, as the reaction-time is not really critical! You just need to implement it into the bus-interface.

**Appendix 2:**

As you asked, i'll detail some parts used.

- Off-the-shelf M0+ uC for the bin controller
- x86 IPC
- RS485 transreceiver (12MBit/s but used at 1MBit/s) for upto 256 nodes
- Off-the-shelf 24/3V3-100mA DC/DC PCB-mount module (100mA is peak...During "standby" only ~5mA are used per bin. If the LEDs are active and the bus is driven, more current is required)
- Off-the-shelf "industrial" 230/24 10A SMPS
- Off-the-shelf bar-code reader (Phillips if i remeber correctly - but please don't quote)
- 120Ohm 50cm cables (between bins) pre-assembled for us for RS485 and standard .5mm² for 24V

**Hope this gives you some introduction and some ideas to play with**

Comment: Want to say thank you for so much for this answer.  This is very informative.  This is actually how I was planning on making it work but could not figure out the bin hardware side.  I am looking into the M0 chips from your comment and the RS485 in more detail. 
 My chip knowledge has stayed very high level and simple on arduino, RPi and eps32s.  Updated my current testing setup which is similar to your example for the software side.

Comment: @BrinkDaDrink You are welcome. Commonly, STM-32 ARM Controllers are used for such projects ase they are wide-spread and well received. The Code-Base available for free is extensive mostly well documented. RS485 is quiete simple to "integrate into a PCB" actually. Many TI AppNotes can be found via google. Also, a range of "eval-boards" for prototyping exists (Raspberry PI, STM-32 and so on).